# ネストされたif文を簡略化したいのですが、うまい書き方を教えていただきたいです

Tags: java, java8

下記のような実装についてうまい修正方法を教えていただきたいです

```java
private boolean isChange(String oldStr, String newStr){
 if(StringUtils.isEmpty(oldStr)){
  if(StringUtils.isEmpty(newStr)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
 } else if (StringUtils.isEmpty(newStr)){
  return true;
 }
 if(!oldStr.equals(newStr)){
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Comment: `if(StringUtils.isEmpty(oldStr)){ if(StringUtils.isEmpty(newStr)){ return true; }else{ return false;}` の部分ですが、`oldStr` と `newStr` が両方ともに空文字列の場合に `true` を返して、`oldStr` が空文字列で `newStr` が空文字列ではない場合に `false` を返します。これは逆ではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

true が返る条件は,newが空であり、old.epual(new)がfalseの場合
つまり

```
private boolean isChange(old, new){
  if(StringUtils.isEmpty(new)){
    return true;
  }else{
    return !old.equal(new)
  }
}
```

もっと短くするのであれば下でも行けるかと。
可読性下がるのでおすすめはしませんが。

```
return StringUtils.isEmpty(new) ? (true) : (!old.equal(new))
```

あと、"new"は予約語なので適切な変数名にしたほうが良いです。
引数の型宣言もないので適切にする必要があります。

Comment: ぬるぽ例外が意外と罠なんですかね？

Comment: コンパイルエラーがあります。equalはequalsの間違いですね。isChange("", "aaa")の場合、質問された方のコードと異なる動きをします。 metropolisさんのコメントどおり、回答された方のコードの方が正しいと思います。isChange("", "")のときtrueになるのは質問された方も回答のコードも誤りだと思います。

Answer (score 1):

> 下記のような実装についてうまい修正方法を教えていただきたいです

isChangeのメソッド名から、新旧に変動があった場合はtrue、変動がなかったらfalseを返すメソッドを作りたいのだと勝手に解釈しました。

以下はコードの修正例です。StringUtilsは使っていません。
`null`と`""`空文字列を同一視しません。`null`から`""`に変化する場合、その逆も変動したと判定します。

```java
private boolean isChange(String oldStr, String newStr) {
    if (oldStr == null && newStr == null) {
        return false;   //変動なし
    }
    else if (oldStr == null || newStr == null) {
        return true;    //変動あり
    }
    else if (newStr.equals(oldStr)) {
        return false;   //変動なし
    } else {
        return true;    //変動あり
    }
}
```

---

metropolisさんのコメントを参考に`StringUtils`を調べてみました。
次のコードは`null`と`""`空文字列を同一視します。`null`から`""`に変化する場合、その逆も変動なしと判定します。

```java
if (StringUtils.isEmpty(oldStr) && StringUtils.isEmpty(newStr)) {
    return false;
}
else if (StringUtils.equals(oldStr, newStr)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

次のコードは`null`と`""`空文字列を同一視しません。`null`から`""`に変化する場合、その逆も変動ありと判定します。

```java
private  boolean isChange(String oldStr, String newStr) {
    return !StringUtils.equals(oldStr, newStr);
}
```

Comment: [StringUtils.equals()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#equals-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) は "**nulls are handled without exceptions**" ですので、`newStr.equals(oldStr)` を `StringUtils.equals(oldStr, newStr)` に書き替えると、`else if (oldStr == null || newStr == null) { return true; }` の部分は不要になります。

Comment: StringUtils.equals()を調べてみました。使ったことがなく勉強になりました。metropolisさん、ありがとうございました。

Comment: とてもわかりやすい、説明ありがとうございます！